# Use results from foreach loop in other part of the script

Tags: perl

I'm using a foreach loop in my code

```
foreach $c1(sort {$a<=>$b} keys %info ) {
    print $c1, "\t", 
          join(',',@{$info{$c1}->{var1}}), "\t", 
          join(',',@{$info{$c1}->{var2}}), "\n";
}
```

When I run my code the output of the ´foreach´ is printed on the screen.

I want however to use the results of the 'foreach' loop in some other parts of my script. How can I do this? Should I assign a variable inside the loop or before?

Comment: What do you mean by "results"? Do you want to store the same strings you output? Do you want to store the order of the elements returned by the sort?

Comment: Well `print` is not the best bet to save transformed data. If you want to save, say a group of products from each element of a collection (hash or array), you should learn about *pipelines* or [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) transformations..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but if you just want to save that string you're building, it's pretty simple:

```
    my $result = "";
    foreach $c1 (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %info) {
      $result .= $c1 . "\t" . 
        join(',',@{$info{$c1}->{var1}}) . "\t" . 
        join(',',@{$info{$c1}->{var2}}) . "\n";
    }
```

Then you can print `$result` or send it to other functions or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something of this kind.
Push your result into array.
push(@array,$c1);
Now you can use @array anywhere in the program.